# ASP.NET Core 3.1 Razor pages - adding different child objects to header

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, partial-views

I'm new to web app development, and I wonder if somebody could point me in the right direction with this?  I think I know what the problem is, but I don't know how to fix it.

What I have is a complex model where a header can contain a child, and each child can itself have its own children (of different types).

My demo code shown here has a header, and two lists. If I click the button to add a child item to either the first list or a second list, the initial problem I have is that the items don't appear.   The other problem is that I don't appear to be able to keep on adding items to either list.

To try to see what is going on, I added a section to show the innerHTML to see what the data is - and this illustrates that if I click to add to the first list, some data appears for the first list, but if I click to add to the second list, the new data disappears from the first list whilst the new item appears as expected in the second list.

I think the problem is that the Model isn't updated to reflect the new items - but I understand that we shouldn't be able to do that with Javascript anyway.  So, I think I need to separate all my partial views, so I have a main partial view containing lots of partial views, and when my Ajax call is successful, refresh the MAIN partial view.

My PageModel class

```
namespace ParentChildDemo.Pages
{
    public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly ILogger<IndexModel> _logger;

        [BindProperty]
        public Header MyHeader { get; set; } = new Header();

        public IndexModel(ILogger<IndexModel> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public void OnGet()
        {
            MyHeader.Id = 1;
            MyHeader.MyHeaderProperty = "HeaderTest1";
            MyHeader.ChildOfHeader.Add(new ChildOfHeader());

            for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
            {
                var childOfChild = new ChildOfChild()
                {
                    Id = i,
                    HeaderId = MyHeader.Id,
                    MyChildProperty = $"FirstChildTest{i}"
                };

                MyHeader.ChildOfHeader[0].MyFirstChildList.Add(childOfChild);
            }

            for (int i = 1; i <= 2; i++)
            {
                var childOfChild = new ChildOfChild()
                {
                    Id = i,
                    HeaderId = MyHeader.Id,
                    MyChildProperty = $"SecondChildTest{i}"
                };

                MyHeader.ChildOfHeader[0].MySecondChildList.Add(childOfChild);
            }
        }

        public PartialViewResult OnPostAddNewFirstListChildItem([FromBody] Header myHeader)
        {
            if (myHeader.ChildOfHeader[0].MyFirstChildList == null)
                myHeader.ChildOfHeader[0].MyFirstChildList = new List<ChildOfChild>();

            var childId = myHeader.ChildOfHeader[0].MyFirstChildList.Count + 1;

            myHeader.ChildOfHeader[0].MyFirstChildList.Add(new ChildOfChild
            {
                Id = childId,
                HeaderId = myHeader.Id,
                MyChildProperty = $"FirstChildTest{childId}"
            });

            var partialView = "_ListPartialView";
            //var partialView = "_FirstListItemPartial";

            var data = new IndexModel(_logger);
            data.MyHeader = myHeader;

            var myViewData = new ViewDataDictionary(new EmptyModelMetadataProvider(), new ModelStateDictionary()) { { partialView, myHeader } };
            //var myViewData = new ViewDataDictionary(new EmptyModelMetadataProvider(), new ModelStateDictionary()) { { partialView, myHeader.ChildOfHeader[0].MyFirstChildList } };
            myViewData.Model = data;

            var partialViewResult = new PartialViewResult()
            {
                ViewName = partialView,
                ViewData = myViewData,
            };

            return partialViewResult;
        }

        public PartialViewResult OnPostAddNewSecondListChildItem([FromBody] Header myHeader)
        {
            if (myHeader.ChildOfHeader[0].MySecondChildList == null)
                myHeader.ChildOfHeader[0].MySecondChildList = new List<ChildOfChild>();

            var childId = myHeader.ChildOfHeader[0].MySecondChildList.Count + 1;

            myHeader.ChildOfHeader[0].MySecondChildList.Add(new ChildOfChild
            {
                Id = childId,
                HeaderId = myHeader.Id,
                MyChildProperty = $"SecondChildTest{childId}"
            });

            var partialView = "_ListPartialView";
            //var partialView = "_SecondListItemPartial";

            var data = new IndexModel(_logger);
            data.MyHeader = myHeader;

            var myViewData = new ViewDataDictionary(new EmptyModelMetadataProvider(), new ModelStateDictionary()) { { partialView, myHeader } };
            //var myViewData = new ViewDataDictionary(new EmptyModelMetadataProvider(), new ModelStateDictionary()) { { partialView, myHeader.ChildOfHeader[0].MySecondChildList } };
            myViewData.Model = data;

            var partialViewResult = new PartialViewResult()
            {
                ViewName = partialView,
                ViewData = myViewData,
            };

            return partialViewResult;
        }
    }

    public class Header
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string MyHeaderProperty { get; set; }
        public List<ChildOfHeader> ChildOfHeader { get; set; } = new List<ChildOfHeader>();
    }

    public class ChildOfHeader
    {
        public List<ChildOfChild> MyFirstChildList { get; set; } = new List<ChildOfChild>();
        public List<ChildOfChild> MySecondChildList { get; set; } = new List<ChildOfChild>();
    }

    public class ChildOfChild
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int HeaderId { get; set; }
        public string MyChildProperty { get; set; }
    }
}
```

My Index page

```
@page
@model IndexModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home page";
}

<div class="text-center">
    <h1 class="display-4">Welcome</h1>
    <p>Learn about <a href="https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core">building Web apps with ASP.NET Core</a>.</p>
</div>

<div>
    <a class="btn btn-sm btn-info text-white" onclick="AddListItem(1)">Add Child to First list</a>
    <a class="btn btn-sm btn-info text-white" onclick="AddListItem(2)">Add Child to Second list</a>
</div>

<br />

<div>
    <div><b>MyHeaderProperty value:</b> @Model.MyHeader.MyHeaderProperty</div>
    <br />
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-6 font-weight-bold">First List</div>
            <div class="col-6 font-weight-bold">Second List</div>
        </div>
        <div class="ListPartialView">
            <partial name="_ListPartialView" model="@Model" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="bg-warning" id="HtmlContent"></div>
    
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function AddListItem(listNumber) {
        var model = @Json.Serialize(Model.MyHeader);

        var handler;
        var partialView;

        if (listNumber == 1) {
            handler = "?handler=AddNewFirstListChildItem";
            partialView = "#ListPartialView";//"#FirstListPartial";
        }
        else {
            handler = "?handler=AddNewSecondListChildItem";
            partialView = "#ListPartialView";//"#SecondListPartial";
        }

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: handler,
            data: JSON.stringify(model),
            dataType: "html",
            contentType: "application/json",
            headers: {
                RequestVerificationToken: $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val()
            },
            success: function (result) {
                document.getElementById("HtmlContent").innerHTML = result.toString();
                $(partialView).html(result);
            },
            failure: function (result) {
                alert("Failed");
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

My Main partial view (_ListPartialView)

```
@model IndexModel

@for (int i = 0; i < Model.MyHeader.ChildOfHeader.Count; i++)
{
    ViewData["ChildIndex"] = i;

    <div class="row">
        <div id="FirstListPartial" class="col-6">
            <partial name="_FirstListItemPartial" model="@Model" view-data="ViewData" />
        </div>
        <div id="SecondListPartial" class="col-6">
            <partial name="_SecondListItemPartial" model="@Model" view-data="ViewData" />
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

My first list partial view (_FirstListItemPartial)

```
@model IndexModel

@{ 
    var indexId = (int)ViewData["ChildIndex"];
}


<table>
    @foreach (var myChildItem in Model.MyHeader.ChildOfHeader[indexId].MyFirstChildList)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@myChildItem.Id</td>
            <td>@myChildItem.MyChildProperty</td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

My second list partial view (_SecondListItemPartial)

```
@model IndexModel

@{
    var indexId = (int)ViewData["ChildIndex"];
}

<table>
    @foreach (var myChildItem in Model.MyHeader.ChildOfHeader[indexId].MySecondChildList)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@myChildItem.Id</td>
            <td>@myChildItem.MyChildProperty</td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `data: JSON.stringify(model),` can just be `data: model,` as jQuery will do that automatically. `url: handler,` here your `handler` object is not a url but just a parameter - which should be part of the data being passed instead perhaps?  What controller method are you calling to return the JSON (like `JsonResult` or one of the similar `IActionResult` etc. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/advanced/formatting?view=aspnetcore-3.1  By the way, where do you put jQuery on your page?  Move that JavaScript to a separate file and link to that rather than all that on the page

Comment: You might just have `<script>
        var model = @Json.Serialize(Model.MyHeader);</script>` but what is it really used for?  Seems improper perhaps to do this in this scenario?

Comment: why is this not in the model? `@{ 
    var indexId = (int)ViewData["ChildIndex"];
}`  There is almost too much here to really cover in one question.

Comment: Thanks for your comments.  My project isn't an MVC project (I think its referred to as an MVVM project?) and so it hasn't got any Controllers.  I swapped the `data: JSON.stringify(model)` for `data: model` as suggested, but this errors in my OnPostAddNewFirstListChildItem method because myHeader is null.  I'm still in the early stages of learning about this, so I'm not sure how to pass my data any other way at the moment. In my real solution, I have separation - so my Javascript is separate.  I just provided everything as concisely as I could for this demo.

Comment: MVVM is really a design pattern so just an abstraction layer on top of MVC - from a simplistic standpoint but yes worth noting and also from an equally simplistic standpoint the ViewModel is just a DTO to the view to abstract if from the model to separate that model from the UI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> if I click to add to the first list, some data appears for the first
> list, but if I click to add to the second list, the new data
> disappears from the first list whilst the new item appears as expected
> in the second list.

If you set a break point in the AddListItem() function or the OnPostAddNewSecondListChildItem() method, you will find that the myHeader object is the original object, it doesn't contain the new items. I think the issue is related that since you are using JQuery ajax to load the partial view, the Index page not refresh and the Model is not update, so, when using this script(`var model = @Json.Serialize(Model.MyHeader);`) to get the model data, it will always get the original value.

To solve this issue, you could try to use session to store the latest data, before add new items, you could get the latest data first, then add new item.

Change your code as below (**Updated**):

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function AddListItem(listNumber) {
            //var model = @Json.Serialize(Model.MyHeader);  
            var model;
            //get the latest daa
            $.ajax({
                type: "get",
                url: "?handler=GetLatestData",
                async: false,
                contentType: "application/json", 
                success: function (data) {
                    model = data;
                }
            });  
            var handler;
            var partialView;

            if (listNumber == 1) {
                handler = "?handler=AddNewFirstListChildItem";
                partialView = "#FirstListPartial";//"#ListPartialView";
            }
            else {
                handler = "?handler=AddNewSecondListChildItem";
                partialView = "#SecondListPartial";//"#SecondListPartial";
            }

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: handler,
                data: JSON.stringify(model),
                dataType: "html",
                contentType: "application/json",
                headers: {
                    RequestVerificationToken: $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val()
                },
                success: function (result) {
                    //document.getElementById("HtmlContent").innerHTML = result.toString();
                    $(partialView).html("");
                    $(partialView).html(result);
                },
                failure: function (result) {
                    alert("Failed");
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
```

and :

```
    public void OnGet()
    {
        MyHeader.Id = 1;
        MyHeader.MyHeaderProperty = "HeaderTest1";
        MyHeader.ChildOfHeader.Add(new ChildOfHeader());

        for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
        {
            var childOfChild = new ChildOfChild()
            {
                Id = i,
                HeaderId = MyHeader.Id,
                MyChildProperty = $"FirstChildTest{i}"
            };

            MyHeader.ChildOfHeader[0].MyFirstChildList.Add(childOfChild);
        }

        for (int i = 1; i <= 2; i++)
        {
            var childOfChild = new ChildOfChild()
            {
                Id = i,
                HeaderId = MyHeader.Id,
                MyChildProperty = $"SecondChildTest{i}"
            };

            MyHeader.ChildOfHeader[0].MySecondChildList.Add(childOfChild);
        }

        if (HttpContext.Session.Get<Header>("HeaderData") == null)
        {
            HttpContext.Session.Set<Header>("HeaderData", MyHeader);
        }
    }

    public PartialViewResult OnPostAddNewFirstListChildItem([FromBody] Header myHeader)
    {
        if (myHeader.ChildOfHeader[0].MyFirstChildList == null)
            myHeader.ChildOfHeader[0].MyFirstChildList = new List<ChildOfChild>();

        var childId = myHeader.ChildOfHeader[0].MyFirstChildList.Count + 1;

        myHeader.ChildOfHeader[0].MyFirstChildList.Add(new ChildOfChild
        {
            Id = childId,
            HeaderId = myHeader.Id,
            MyChildProperty = $"FirstChildTest{childId}"
        });

        //var partialView = "_ListPartialView";
        var partialView = "_FirstListItemPartial";

        var data = new IndexModel(_logger);
        data.MyHeader = myHeader;

        var myViewData = new ViewDataDictionary(new EmptyModelMetadataProvider(), new ModelStateDictionary()) { { partialView, myHeader } };
        //var myViewData = new ViewDataDictionary(new EmptyModelMetadataProvider(), new ModelStateDictionary()) { { partialView, myHeader.ChildOfHeader[0].MyFirstChildList } };
        myViewData.Model = data;

        var partialViewResult = new PartialViewResult()
        {
            ViewName = partialView,
            ViewData = myViewData,
        };
        
        HttpContext.Session.Set<Header>("HeaderData", myHeader);

        return partialViewResult;
    }

    public PartialViewResult OnPostAddNewSecondListChildItem([FromBody] Header myHeader)
    {
        if (myHeader.ChildOfHeader[0].MySecondChildList == null)
            myHeader.ChildOfHeader[0].MySecondChildList = new List<ChildOfChild>();

        var childId = myHeader.ChildOfHeader[0].MySecondChildList.Count + 1;

        myHeader.ChildOfHeader[0].MySecondChildList.Add(new ChildOfChild
        {
            Id = childId,
            HeaderId = myHeader.Id,
            MyChildProperty = $"SecondChildTest{childId}"
        });

        //var partialView = "_ListPartialView";
        var partialView = "_SecondListItemPartial";

        var data = new IndexModel(_logger);
        data.MyHeader = myHeader;

        var myViewData = new ViewDataDictionary(new EmptyModelMetadataProvider(), new ModelStateDictionary()) { { partialView, myHeader } };
        //var myViewData = new ViewDataDictionary(new EmptyModelMetadataProvider(), new ModelStateDictionary()) { { partialView, myHeader.ChildOfHeader[0].MySecondChildList } };
        myViewData.Model = data;

        var partialViewResult = new PartialViewResult()
        {
            ViewName = partialView,
            ViewData = myViewData,
        };
        HttpContext.Session.Set<Header>("HeaderData", myHeader);
        return partialViewResult;
    }
    public JsonResult OnGetGetLatestData()
    {
        var result = new Header();
        if (HttpContext.Session.Get<Header>("HeaderData") != null)
        {
            result = HttpContext.Session.Get<Header>("HeaderData");
        };
        return new JsonResult(result);
    }
```

screenshot (**Updated**):

[image]

To use session in asp.net core application, see [Session and state management in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-3.1#session-state)

[Note] if you want to use the session to store complex object, you have to add the SessionExtensions.

Comment: Many thanks for this.  I still have much to learn!  I am not in a position to try it until tomorrow - is it going to be straightforward enough to change the content of the real lists (not the bit shown in orange)?

Comment: I have got it working the way you have illustrated, but now that I have removed the orange coloured div (which was only there to indicate that something was happening), the first list and second list do not increment.  If I put a breakpoint in the _FirstListItemPartial, for example, I can see that it loops through the correct number of rows, but it does not output all of the ```tr```.  I do not know why.

Comment: @WayneReynolds, In the JavaScript AddListItem() function, you have to change the outputs partial view name to the children partial, like this: `partialView = "#FirstListPartial";//"#ListPartialView";` and in the OnPostAddNewFirstListChildItem() and OnPostAddNewSecondListChildItem method, change the `var partialView = "_ListPartialView";` to `var partialView = "_FirstListItemPartial"` or `var partialView = "_SecondListItemPartial";`. I have updated the code and screenshot in my reply, please check it.

Comment: thanks for your reply.  Did you do anything in the _FirstListItemPartial (and _SecondListItemPartial)?  Mine does not work because the ```ViewData["ChildIndex"]``` hasn't been populated via the _ListPartialView.  I need it to go through _ListPartialView because I use this ViewData to provide some div Id's in my main app.

Comment: Yes, I check it is null before using it. code like this: `@{ var indexId = 0; if (ViewData["ChildIndex"] != null)  {  indexId = (int)ViewData["ChildIndex"];  }}`

Comment: It seems that when add new items, the ViewData["ChildIndex"] always null, in my sample, it will using the default value "0".  I suppose you want to transfer the ChildIndex value from the "_ListPartialView" to the "_FirstListItemPartial" and "_SecondListItemPartial", right? To solve this issue, in the AddListItem function, you could get the ChildIndex first (via a hidden field), then send the value to the OnPostAddNewFirstListChildItem method, after that in the Post method, using the following code to add the ChildIndex to the ViewDataDictionary: `myViewData.Add("ChildIndex", childIndex);`.

Comment: Perfect.  Thank you so much.  This concept should hopefully transfer to my main app.